# Platformer movement disabled after crouching

Tags: unity, c#, movement, platformer

So, the problem is the movement to left and right is disabled after crouching and releasing

```
void Crouch()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C))
    {
        movementSpeed /= 2f;
        anim.SetTrigger("crouch");
        rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionY;
        cd.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>().enabled = false;
        cd.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        movementSpeed /= 1f;
        anim.SetTrigger("idle");
        cd.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>().enabled = true;
        cd.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How you call this Crouch method?

Comment: figured it out, so every time the key is held the movement speed divides by 2 for every second finally going to a negative value.